# I unlocked the 'Files' button/icon from my unity launcher and now it disappearead and I cannot restore it or get it back

Tags: unity, launcher, files, 16.04

I unlocked the 'Files' button for the Ubuntu file manager from the unity launcher and I cannot get it back.

When I run the file manager from the dash, the icon does not appear on the launcher like it does for all other applications while they are running.
I wanted to have an empty launcher when no applications are running, and just have the icons of those I am actively using there.

Any idea why I don't see it in the launcher when its running or how to lock it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it back:

- Run nautilus from Dash
- Browse to `/usr/share/applications`
- Drag the file `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` to the Unity Launcher

That should do it.

Question remains why it does not appear in the launcher if you run it from Dash. Possibly a log out / in would have changed that.

Comment: Logging out and in does not fix the problem but your solution worked for getting it back on the launcher. Thanks!

Comment: @lolero glad it works!

Comment: There's a simpler method. See my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it. When you start `files` again its icon appears way down on the launcher so you probably will not see it:

[image: screenshot]

Move the mouse pointer to the lower end of the launcher and those icons get expanded

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  
I don't know why but I restarted my computer and the icon of Files appear again in the launcher.  
Everything good now.  
Solution : Have You Tried Turning It Off And On Again?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't see it in the Launcher due to the number of shortcuts there. Once you exceed the maximum that will fit flat, they start getting squashed/overlapped and you may have to roll them up (pointer to top) and down (pointer to bottom) in order to see the one you are looking for.

Easiest method:

1) Find Nautilus in the dash (type <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> in the box) and The files Icon will show up as seen here:

[image: na1]

If you don't see it Make sure <kbd>Applications</kbd> is selected under Categories in the Dash Filter Results settings.

2) Drag the file cabinet from the dash screen and drop it on the launcher bar wherever you like. Viola it's back as seen here (6th icon from the top):

[image: na2]

You can put it back in it's original location by dragging to the right off the launcher and back to the launcher approaching from the right to the desired location and dropping it there if you so desire.

Tested on 14.04 and 16.04
Note: On 16.04 this has the side effect of replacing the default folder icon with the file drawer icon.

Comment: I am afraid that wasn't the issue. I had it too a while after this question, the icon was really invisible, not as a result of overpopulation :)